# How to remove a composite partition in DolphinDB

Tags: partitioning, dolphindb

To remote a composite partition in DolphinDB database, do I have to manually delete all first-level partition? Is there a command to do it in one line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DolphinDB 0.96.0 supports this feature.

```
dropPartition(dbHandle, partitionPaths, [tableName], [forceDelete=false])
```

partitionPaths can either be dfs path relative to the database or filtering criteria. http://www.dolphindb.com/help/index.html?dropPartition.html